# Reference going to the page of an object

Tags: hyperref

The following code will create a reference to the caption of the image

```
\hyperref[fig:1]{Figure \ref*{fig:1} on page \pageref*{fig:1}}
```

I'd like the reference brings me on the top of the page containing `fig:1`, rather than the caption of the image, how to do that?

Comment: Package `hypcap` or `caption` move the reference to the top of the figure.

Comment: Yea, it works!
Just add `\usepackage{caption}` at the top of the document